# Check for column existence in mySQL

Tags: mysql, matlab, exists

I know this question has been asked before, but for some reason the suggested solutions do not work in my setup. 
 I am calling a mySQL database from within matlab on windows, and need to check whether a given table has a specific column before my script commences calculating values for that column.
From previous answers, I get that the following should help me determine if col1 exists:

```
select exists (select * from table1 where col1=val1)
```

And this works fine if col1 exists. However, when it doesn't I get the following:

```
>> fetch(conn,'select exists (select * from model12B where col1=.5)')

Error using database/fetch (line 37)
[MySQL][ODBC 5.3(a) Driver][mysqld-5.5.37-log]Unknown column 'col1' in 'where clause'
```

This looks more like a MySQL error than a matlab error, hence why I'm framing it as a MySQL question. I can of course wrap this in a try-catch block, but that feels wrong. Can anyone suggest a good way to ask for existence without generating an error?

Comment: If you need to do this, something is seriously wrong with your design

Comment: @Strawberry: that's an awfully prejudiced comment. I use a database to collect simulation results for a family of mathematical models. as results are collected, entries are made in the database. as the models are different, different information needs to be saved (hence different columns in different tables). I hope you will agree that keeping descriptions of my tables in multiple places is more error prone than having the descriptions in one place. If I just ask the table what information it is expecting, I only have make my changes in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the information_schema to tell you if the column exists in specified database and specified table :

```
 select * from information_schema.columns where table_name='tablename' and table_schema='databasename' and and column_name='columnname'
```

Or you can use "show columns " command:

```
 show columns from databasename.tablename where like 'columnname';
```

Of course, you can use the try - catch to test if a column exists of not. I don't think there is any side effect if you analyze the error message carefully.